# Bot builder Sdk is the only way to create chatbot with luis? how to add bot response in luis

Tags: bots, azure-language-understanding

I have created a agent in luis with entities and intents and I am unable to add bot response in luis as i can do it in Google API AI 
can I use luis directly from my node App ??

Answer (score 1):

In your node application, you can install the botbuilder package which includes what you need to connect a node app to luis.

> npm install botbuilder

Then in your node app,

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
```

The builder module already has what you need to connect to LUIS.

From then, here's how you can connect to your LUIS application:

```js
function initLuisRecognizer(){
    const luisAppID = "Your-luis-app-id"
    const subscriptionKey = "Your-Luis-Sub-Key"
    return new builder.LuisRecognizer(luisAppID, subscriptionKey);
}
var luisRecognizer = initLuisRecognizer();
```

For more samples, you can check out the [botbuilder-samples repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node). There are a few Node.js bot samples which use LUIS.

### However, if you **DON'T** want to use the botbuilder SDK,

you can use the [Programmatic API from LUIS](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f)

https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/

There are several examples in different languages, for example, in Javascript, using ajax:

```js
     $.ajax({
            url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/?" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","{subscription key}");
            },
            type: "POST",
            // Request body
            data: "{body}",
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
```

Hope that helps!